# Which package makes conda downgrade a package?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am installing a rather long list of packages with `conda` with the following command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge \
    'nomkl' \
    'ipywidgets=7.4.0' \
    'pandas=0.23.4' \
    'numexpr=2.6.5' \
    'matplotlib=2.2.2' \
    'scipy=1.1.0' \
    'seaborn=0.9.0' \
    'scikit-learn=0.19.1' \
    'scikit-image=0.14.0' \
    'sympy=1.2' \
    'cython=0.28.5' \
    'patsy=0.5.0' \
    'statsmodels=0.8.0' \
    'dill=0.2.8.2' \
    'numba=0.38.1' \
    'bokeh=0.13.0' \
    'sqlalchemy=1.2.10' \
    'hdf5' \
    'libnetcdf' \
    'netcdf4' \
    'h5py=2.8.0' \
    'vincent=0.4.4' \
    'beautifulsoup4=4.6.1' \
    'protobuf=3.6.0' \
    'tensorflow=1.10' \
    'opencv' \
    'keras=2.1' \
    'dask=0.19.0' \
    'dask-glm=0.1.0' \
    'dask-ml=0.9.0' \
    'dask-xgboost=0.1.5' \
    'dask-kubernetes=0.5.0' \
    'msgpack-python' \
    'distributed=1.23' \
    'cloudpickle=0.5.3' \
    'python-blosc' \
    'numpy=1.14.2' \
    'xarray=0.10.8' \
    'gcsfs=0.1.2' \
    'pymc3=3.5' \
    'hdbscan=0.8.15' \
    'pystan=2.17.1.0' \
    'yaafe=0.70' \
    'aubio=0.4.6' \
    'librosa=0.6.2' \
    'nltk=3.2.5' \
    'spacy=2.0.11' \
    'gensim=3.5.0' \
    'textblob=0.15.1' \
    'xlrd=1.1.0'  && \
    conda clean -tipsy
```

As a side effect, following downgrade happens:

```
python: 3.6.5-1 conda-forge --> 3.5.5-1
```

Which actually breaks my environment, as I rely on Python 3.6.

What's the best way to check which package causes the downgrade? Maybe there's a way to fix Python version and make `conda` throw an error on a package that does not meet the constraint?

Comment: You can specify a particular version of Python as a dependency in your list, that will probably pop out the error.

Comment: @darthbith Interestingly, not. When I specify Python version, it actually happily proceeds without downgrading. I was expecting some broken packages, but no. Also, no single package seems to require Python 3.5. It's only when I install together e.g. aubio and librosa that it calls for downgrade. Apparently something about common dependencies.

Comment: I suspected that would happen. I was also recently building a Dockerfile where the same thing happened, and the fix was to specify the Python version. Not ideal, but at least no conflicts! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the following script from your env. For me it links everything to Python 3.6.6, although it fails on xgboost not being available. Likely to be different on your env. All it is is wrapping `conda create` with python script to make it OS independent. It is tested with Python 3.6.6 on Windows.

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE, DEVNULL
import json

deps = ['dask-xgboost=0.1.5', 'nomkl', 'ipywidgets=7.4.0', 'pandas=0.23.4', 'numexpr=2.6.5', 'matplotlib=2.2.2', 'scipy=1.1.0', 'seaborn=0.9.0', 'scikit-learn=0.19.1', 'scikit-image=0.14.0', 'sympy=1.2', 'cython=0.28.5', 'patsy=0.5.0', 'statsmodels=0.8.0', 'dill=0.2.8.2', 'numba=0.38.1', 'bokeh=0.13.0', 'sqlalchemy=1.2.10', 'hdf5', 'libnetcdf', 'netcdf4', 'h5py=2.8.0', 'vincent=0.4.4', 'beautifulsoup4=4.6.1', 'protobuf=3.6.0', 'tensorflow=1.10',     'opencv', 'keras=2.1', 'dask=0.19.0', 'dask-glm=0.1.0', 'dask-ml=0.9.0', 'dask-kubernetes=0.5.0', 'msgpack-python', 'distributed=1.23']

for d in deps:
    links = run('conda create --dry-run --json -n dummy ' + d, stdout=PIPE, stderr=DEVNULL)
    if links.returncode == 0:
        links = json.loads(links.stdout)
        if 'actions' in links:
            links = links['actions']['LINK']
            p = [l for l in links if l['name'] == 'python']
            if len(p): print("{} links python={}".format(d, p[0]['version']))
            else: print("{} - no python".format(d))
        else: print("{} - no actions".format(d))
    else: print("{} failed: {}".format(d, links.stdout.decode('ascii')))
```

Could be more defensive, but I am too lazy, sorry :)

Comment: Nice one! I actually did the same, even more lazily... and nothing. No package I request or its dependency requires Python 3.6. What turns out is that only certain combinations, e.g. aubio and librosa, call for the downgrade.Then I also found on some other combinations it offers me downgrade to e.g. Python 3.6.3. I gave up after that. Now I just specify Python version.

Comment: Your script essentially answers the question so I am going to accept it as the answer. Thanks!